# Laravel apply form with oauth2 - conceptional question

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, discord

I try to build an application form, where you have to connect with the discord oauth2 after submitting the application. So I already got the whole oauth set up and I could make a button where you connect with discord and then fill out your form. But I'd like to have the form submit and oauth request with the same button. Now the problem I'm facing, I can't pass adittional data through the oauth request.

My 'applications' table has id, discord_id and form data columns. So my first idea was to just store the form data and make a redirect to the discord oauth page, then return back to the controller and add the id. The problem, I can't pass additional data to the oauth, so I wouldn't be able to assign the users discord id correctly.

Maybe you guys have any ideas or already worked with discord oauth2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are after the OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant.

Discord's developer site has a guide on doing this [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2).

A basic idea of how it would function is as follows:

1. The user clicks the "Connect with Discord" button which redirects the user to the Discord's Authorisation URL containing your developer application client id and scopes
2. The user enters their details in to the Discord site's login page and clicks Login
3. Once authenticated with Discord, the user would need to approve your application to access their profile information in Discord
4. Once approved, Discord redirects the user back to your website and passes a Authorisation Code via GET
5. Your website then makes a separate request (from the server) to Discord to request a Authorisation Token which you can then use to request the user's information from Discord

You mentioned that you are using Laravel, I would strongly suggest you take a look at [Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite) which will handle a lot of this logic for you.

You can then use the [Discord Socialite Provider](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Discord) to handle the logic for Discord specifically.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I already got the whole discord oauth part done working. The only problem I'm facing is, how can I pass form data to my controller, and then redirect to discord and back, get the user's information and store it together with my data from the form. Also socialite doesn't has a discord driver included. So I only need to get the user's discord id once, so using a whole package for that seems kinda too much for me.